# How to get between two br tags in xpath?

Tags: xpath, domxpath

I have a table with td like this

```
<td>
   <span> Washington US <br>98101 Times Square</span>
</td>
```

I can get all the elements in the page, but I need to get those two values separately. If that isn't possible I would like to somehow get `98101 Times Square`

I have tried doing something like `string(//tr[3]//td[2])/` but all I get is the two text joined together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the text child nodes in the `span` element with `span/text()` so assuming your posted path selects the `td` containing the `span` you want `//tr[3]//td[2]/span/text()`.

Here is a sample:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<html>
  <body>
     <table>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>3,1</td>
     <td>
   <span> Washington US <br>98101 Times Square</span>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>

EOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);


$textNodes = $xpath->query('//tr[3]//td[2]/span/text()');

foreach ($textNodes as $text) {
    echo $text->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
 Washington US 
98101 Times Square
```

Comment: But there is only one span, how do I select parent/child?

Comment: @mvrht, I don't understand why a single span is a problem with the path I suggested. I have added a code snippet, perhaps that helps.

Comment: My bad. I thought I didn't have to do foreach. I assumed the xpath would split and return it as array

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
td/span/node()[1]
```

and

```
td/span/node()[3]
```

Or

```
td/span/text()[1]
td/span/text()[2]
```